# `Universe` - but for small and finite enumeration of ADTs

Tags: haskell, routes, enumeration

I want to generically derive *something like* `Universe` for user's route type defined in terms of ADTs.

**Problem**: I can use neither `Enum`/`Bounded` nor `Universe` - because they are not safe. The default instances on types like `Int64` can lead to gazillion routes being generated.

The following route is valid, and should be accepted because there is a small and finite number of routes:

```hs
data R = Index | Blog BlogR
data BlogR = Foo | Bar
```

The following route is invalid, and should not be accepted because there is an infinite number of routes generateble due to `String`. Neither should finitely enumerable types like `Int64` be accepted.

```hs
data R = Index | Blog BlogR
data BlogR = Post String
```

The following route seems valid, but it should not be accepted either due to recursion.

```hs
data R = Index | Blog BlogR
data BlogR = Foo | Bar | Rec R
```

**Questions**:

- Is there an existing type class that captures this constraint? If not, I would create one.
- How to generically (`generics-sop`?) derive instances to capture this constraint, and fail with an user-friendly `TypeError` on invalid types?
- Are there better ways of approaching this problem? Ultimately, I want a default implementation for `IsRoute r => allRoutes :: [r]`. At the moment, I use `Enum` and `Bounded` ([see real-world code here](https://github.com/srid/ema/blob/40ef7f0e152cda8791e5a8086f4ef6b15cb8fd1c/src/Ema/Class.hs#L19-L21)) which is limiting because it cannot handle the first route type above.

---

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no existing type class that captures this type of constraint.

The challenge in defining a generics-based answer seems to be ruling out the recursion, as demonstrated below.  I think the simplest approach is probably to use a counter that sets an upper limit on the "depth" of a type.  The alternative would be to keep a type-level list of types already visited which seems like way too much trouble to be worth it.

So, here's a solution that uses `GHC.Generics` together with a type family constraint to enforce non-recursion (or technically, limited "depth" of the type).

Perhaps you're already familiar with the general `GHC.Generics` approach, but for completeness, here's how we'd put together a solution without worrying about recursion yet.  We start with the type class we want to define:

```
class Small a where
  universe :: [a]
```

Then, we introduce a stylized generic type class, where the generic type `a` is replaced by a type `f p` such that `f` will play the role of the type-level representation `Rep a` of the type `a` we want to handle generically, while `p` is a dummy type variable that's never used:

```
import GHC.Generics

class GSmall f where
  guniverse :: [f p]
```

Instances of the `GSmall` type class are defined on types from `GHC.Generics` that represent meta information, sum and product types, and constructor fields.

For meta information (e.g., names of fields, etc.), generic classes like `GSmall` that want to ignore it should simply "get the types right" by wrapping or unwrapping with the `M1` constructor, as appropriate.  Here, we add `M1` to every element of the universe list:

```
instance GSmall f => GSmall (M1 i c f) where
  guniverse = map M1 guniverse
```

For sum and product types, we need instances for the null sum (`Void`) and the null product (`()`) represented by generic types `V1` and `U1` respectively:

```
-- handle uninhabited type Void
instance GSmall V1 where
  guniverse = []
-- handle unit
instance GSmall U1 where
  guniverse = [U1]
```

For binary sums, the type level representation uses the operator `:+:` while the generic inhabitants are represented by the `L1` and `R1` constructors respectively.  Here, by wrapping with the right constructors, we call `guniverse` polymorphically on the left and right types of the sum:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

instance (GSmall f, GSmall g) => GSmall (f :+: g) where
  guniverse = map L1 guniverse ++ map R1 guniverse
```

For binary products, the process is similar, except we want to generate all combinations of the left and right side of the product:

```
instance (GSmall f, GSmall g) => GSmall (f :*: g) where
  guniverse = [f :*: g | f <- guniverse, g <- guniverse]
```

Finally, we handle constructor fields of type `a` by looping back to the concrete `Small` class:

```
instance Small a => GSmall (K1 r a) where
  guniverse = map K1 universe
```

If desired, we can add a default definition for `universe` in the `Small` class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class Small a where
  universe :: [a]
  default universe :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a)) => [a]
  universe = universeGeneric

universeGeneric :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a)) => [a]
universeGeneric = map to guniverse
```

To use this generic instance, we write

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = Foo | Bar deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Small Route
instance Small BlogR

main = print $ universe @Route
```

If you want to use a non-generic instance for some types, you can do that as well by overriding the default `universe` instance:

```
universeEnum :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
universeEnum = [minBound..maxBound]

data BlogR = Foo | Bar deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

instance Small BlogR where universe = universeEnum
```

Here's the complete solution so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Generics

class Small a where
  universe :: [a]
  default universe :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a)) => [a]
  universe = universeGeneric

class GSmall f where
  guniverse :: [f p]

universeGeneric :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a)) => [a]
universeGeneric = map to guniverse

universeEnum :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
universeEnum = [minBound..maxBound]

instance GSmall f => GSmall (M1 i c f) where
  guniverse = map M1 guniverse
instance GSmall V1 where
  guniverse = []
instance GSmall U1 where
  guniverse = [U1]
instance (GSmall f, GSmall g) => GSmall (f :+: g) where
  guniverse = map L1 guniverse ++ map R1 guniverse
instance (GSmall f, GSmall g) => GSmall (f :*: g) where
  guniverse = [f :*: g | f <- guniverse, g <- guniverse]
instance Small a => GSmall (K1 r a) where
  guniverse = map K1 universe

data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = Foo | Bar deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Small Route
-- use generic
instance Small BlogR
-- or enum-based
-- instance Small BlogR where universe = universeEnum

main = print $ universe @Route
```

If you try to generate an instance for a non-recursive, non-small type (using `Int`, for example):

```
data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = PostId Int deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Small Route
instance Small BlogR  -- error
```

you get an error:

```
No instance for (Small Int)
```

which seems user-friendly enough without a `TypeError`.

The one problem is that recursive types *are* accepted, including lists, so we can define:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = PostId String deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Small Route
instance Small BlogR
instance Small String
instance Small Char where universe = universeEnum
```

and get valid instances.  Same for your explicitly recursive example.

I think the simplest way to address this is to define a separate generic type family constraint to check that a type is non-recursive (or more exactly, has a limited depth).  This should include a generics based closed type family, something like the following.  Note that the `top` parameter is used here to remember the top-level type for error messages.  The generic type being processed is `f`, and the family yields an empty constraint if the depth of `f` doesn't exceed the depth "countdown" in `n`, and a `TypeError` otherwise:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

type family GClosed n top f :: Constraint where
  GClosed 0 top f = TypeError (Text "Depth limit exceeded by type: " :<>: ShowType top)
  GClosed n top (M1 i c f) = GClosed n top f
  GClosed n top V1 = ()
  GClosed n top U1 = ()
  GClosed n top (f :+: g) = (GClosed n top f, GClosed n top g)
  GClosed n top (f :*: g) = (GClosed n top f, GClosed n top g)
  GClosed n top (K1 r a) = NClosed (n-1) top a
```

Note that the final case for `K1` calls into an associated `NClosed` type family in the `Small` class, defaulting to the generic assessment of being "closed" via `GClosed`:

```
class Small a where
  ...
  type NClosed (n :: Nat) top a :: Constraint
  type instance NClosed n top a = GClosed n top (Rep a)
```

We can then define:

```
type ClosedLimit = 20
type Closed a = NClosed ClosedLimit a a
```

and sneak this constraint into the definition of `universeGeneric`:

```
universeGeneric :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a), Closed a) => [a]
universeGeneric = map to guniverse
```

(with an associated update to the default `universe` signature in `class Small`).

This separation between `GClosed` and `NClosed` allows us to indicate that non-generic `Small` instances are closed with a little boilerplate.  For example, if we want to allow `Word8`'s to be small:

```
instance Small Word8 where
  universe = universeEnum     -- use enum implementation
  type NClosed n a Int = ()   -- Word8s are closed
```

The full code looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

type Closed a = NClosed ClosedLimit a a
type family GClosed n top f :: Constraint where
  GClosed 0 top f = TypeError (Text "Depth limit exceeded by type: " :<>: ShowType top)
  GClosed n top (M1 i c f) = GClosed n top f
  GClosed n top V1 = ()
  GClosed n top U1 = ()
  GClosed n top (f :+: g) = (GClosed n top f, GClosed n top g)
  GClosed n top (f :*: g) = (GClosed n top f, GClosed n top g)
  GClosed n top (K1 r a) = NClosed (n-1) top a
type ClosedLimit = 20

class Small a where
  universe :: [a]
  default universe :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a), Closed a) => [a]
  universe = universeGeneric
  type NClosed (n :: Nat) top a :: Constraint
  type instance NClosed n top a = GClosed n top (Rep a)

class GSmall f where
  guniverse :: [f p]

universeGeneric :: (Generic a, GSmall (Rep a), Closed a) => [a]
universeGeneric = map to guniverse

universeEnum :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
universeEnum = [minBound..maxBound]

instance GSmall f => GSmall (M1 i c f) where
  guniverse = map M1 guniverse
instance GSmall V1 where
  guniverse = []
instance GSmall U1 where
  guniverse = [U1]
instance (GSmall f, GSmall g) => GSmall (f :+: g) where
  guniverse = map L1 guniverse ++ map R1 guniverse
instance (GSmall f, GSmall g) => GSmall (f :*: g) where
  guniverse = [f :*: g | f <- guniverse, g <- guniverse]
instance Small a => GSmall (K1 r a) where
  guniverse = map K1 universe

data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = Foo | Bar deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Small Route
instance Small BlogR

main = print $ universe @Route
```

Both of your "bad" examples are rejected.  The first:

```
data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = Post String deriving (Show, Generic)
```

generates a couple of nasty error messages about `NClosed` plus the reasonably friendly message:

```
No instance for (Small [Char])
```

Attempts to define `instance Small [Char]` will result in:

```
Depth limit exceeded by type: [Char]
```

while the second:

```
data Route = Index | Blog BlogR deriving (Show, Generic)
data BlogR = Foo | Bar | Rec Route deriving (Show, Generic)
```

generates the message:

```
Depth limit exceeded by type: Route
```

Comment: Instead of reckoning the depth, I guess `Small` could also consider the cardinality directly, along the lines of `class (Data.Universe.Finite a) => Small n a where { cardinalityS :: Tagged a (Data.Finite.Finite n) }`, that is, deriving from the `Finite` class in the `universe` package, statically indexing `Small` with the [maximum] cardinality as a `Finite n` number from `finite-typelits`, and possibly also using a bounded list type `Vec n` / `AtMost n`. However, this might turn out pretty ungainly with the `KnownNat n` plumbing.